# Delphi 7 and Delphi 2010 to Delphi Xe6 Read File Conflict

Tags: delphi

I got this source code but some how I'm confused about the lines why in Delphi 7 the size of the integer is 33 BUT in using Delphi XE6 the size is 65.

I just want to get the same integer value from Delphi XE6 Result is 65 to my Delphi 7 result value is 65 also.

This are the codes.

```
unit Unit1;
interface
uses
Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
Dialogs, StdCtrls;
type
TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
private
    { Private declarations }
public
    { Public declarations }
end;

var
Form1: TForm1;
implementation
{$R *.dfm}

//IS THE PROBLEM IN THIS FUNCTION?
function HeadBufBytes(InFileName: String) : string;
    Inf : TFileStream;
    Buf : array[0..5] of char;
begin
//codes here....
    Inf.ReadBuffer(Buf, SizeOf(Buf));
//codes here...
end;

//EDITED CODES FOR SIMPLE LOOK

procedure ReadDataFile(strFilename : string; strDestDir : string);
var
firstF:file;
posRead,nRead:Integer;
Buf : array[1..2048] of Char;
strHeadByte:string;
begin
strHeadByte:=HeadBufBytes(strFileName);
AssignFile(firstF, strFileName);
Reset(firstF, 1);
BlockRead(firstF, Buf, SizeOf(Buf), nRead);
posRead:=Pos(strHeadByte, Buf);
    //PROBLEM LINE
    //WHAT IS THE PROBLEM IN THIS CODE
    showmessage(inttostr(posRead));
    //IN DELPHI7 THE RESULT IS 33
    //IN DELPHI 2010 TO XE6 THE RESULT IS 65
    //WHAT IS THE PROBLEM IN THIS CODE
    //PROBLEM LINE
CloseFile(firstF);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
ReadDataFile('00001.dat', extractfilepath(application.ExeName));
end;

end.
```

Comment: Perhaps we need to find a good question on this topic that we can close all other such questions as dupes. If there isn't one perhaps we could make one. Any thoughts?

Comment: Just change char to Ansichar

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Well, you have an answer below, so you could use this Qyestion  :-)

Answer (score 5):

```
Buf: array[1..2048] of Char;
```

In your Delphi 7 code, `Char` is an alias for `AnsiChar`, an 8 bit type. Since Delphi 2009, `Char` has been an alias for `WideChar`, a 16 bit type.

Change the declaration to

```
Buf: array[1..2048] of AnsiChar;
```

to make the code behave as before.

Likewise you will need to change

```
Buf: array[0..5] of Char;
```

to

```
Buf: array[0..5] of AnsiChar;
```

Expect to encounter many more similar issues.

Comment: I never thought to change both of them, problem solved, thanks

Comment: FWIW, ISTM that questions like this appear all the time. Isn't this a duplicate of something?

Comment: @Rudy I agree. We should make a question with a comprehensive answer and then close all questions like this as a dupe.

Comment: In my own opinion this is not a duplicate question, because if this is a duplicate question then I should have not ask if I find a solution here, it just turn that I have a different mode of problem.

Comment: That the default Char and string types changed between Delphi 2007 and 2009 is a problem that causes a lot of questions. This includes all kinds of questions due to a migration from a version before Delphi 2009 and a newer one. That includes this one. It is probably not an exact duplicate, but that is why there should be one question that serves as the "base" for all such duplicates.

Comment: @mayzul I think it's probably a dupe of many questions to be honest. As soon as you know that Char means something different it's obvious. That you might not know the search terms needed to find the dupes, doesn't make it not be a dupe. If we know how to find the dupes, then it's all good. Anyway, do you need more help? Or is the Q answered?

Comment: @mayzul: just enter `char ansichar` in the search box at the top right of this page. All duplicates, all resulting from the fact that in Delphi 2009, `Char` and `string` now use UTF-16 instead of codepaged ANSI.